# mysql - error on running the application

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1025

mysql diplay an error

OperationalError: (1025, "Error on rename of './CMMS/#sql-c40_20a' to './CMMS/member' (errno: 150)")

How to solve it??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is an error bubbling up from the underlying database. This error indicates that you cannot rename the table because of some foreign key restrictions on that table. You should check your database logs for more information. For a possible solution you could try to remove the foreign keys first, then move/drop/rename your table.